# Disable emacs-rails mode tab completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

I'm looking to disable (or customized) tab completion in emacs Ruby on Rails mode, specifically code completion. The fact that tab completion overrides using tab for indenting plus the fact that tab completion tries to complete lines like "end" is fairly infuriating.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use tab for indentation, you might try

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (define-key ruby-mode-map [TAB]
               'indent-line)))
```

in your `.emacs`. Note that I tried it with `ruby-mode` and not with `ruby-on-rails-mode`. You probably will have to exchange `'ruby-mode-hook` with `'ruby-on-rails-mode-hook`.

Here are further instructions for keybindings in emacs.

[Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html)

http://emacsblog.org/2007/02/10/quick-tip-defining-mode-specific-key-bindings/

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html

And indentation information.

http://www.xemacs.org/Links/tutorials_1.html